# How to populate a listview from an azure database

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I'm trying to populate a listview with everything from my azure table but cant figure out how.

My app is crashing with this error:

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

What I'm trying to do is, Display everything in the table and have it out, similar to whats commented out, the hardedcoded part.

Here's the page page I'm trying to add it too. But I think my main problem is just getting the list from the database to work with.

```
public class SearchEvent : Activity
{
    public static MobileServiceClient Client =
    new MobileServiceClient("https://app.azurewebsites.net");

    private List<EventsDB> eItems;
    private ListView eListView;

    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ISharedPreferences login = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Login", FileCreationMode.Private);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search_Event);
        eListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        List<EventsDB> eItems = await Client.GetTable<EventsDB>().ToListAsync();

        //eItems = new List<EventsDB>();
        //eItems.Add(new EventsDB() { EventName = allEvents , Location = "Laois", Date = "28/03/18", Category = "Computing", Description = "This is a test" });
        //eItems.Add(new EventsDB() { EventName = "Another", Location = "Carlow", Date = "29/03/18", Category = "Music", Description = "This is another test" });

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, this.eItems);

        eListView.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful if you could include an error or the behavior of the code you've written. The first two lines of code you show are a little confusing. You are creating a List of EventDB objects, but then turn around and try to assign that List to an instance of a EventDB object (singular). That shouldn't even compile, so I'm not sure you are showing what you want to show there.

Comment: @MikeWo I updated it there to try make it more clear. Whats in the last segment of code is whats in the file atm, the above part isn't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, so if anyone else comes across this with the same problem, what I did was changed this:

```
<List<EventsDB> eItems = await Client.GetTable<EventsDB>().ToListAsysnc();
```

To:

```
eItems = await Client.GetTable<EventsDB>().ToListAsysnc();
```

And it worked fine.